How can I tell what cables will be able to send data to my very old iPod Touch?
The cable for my iPod Touch has gone missing. It is a 5th Gen (A1421) model. How can I tell what cables will be able to send data to it? I'll almost certainly have to buy a new one.

Where did you search for info on this iPod Touch?

@IconDaemon You can find it on the device itself. Its in the settings menus.

Your iPod has a Lightning connector (see the iPod Touch specifications page linked by IconDaemon) so you'll need a Lightning cable (that's the cable type Apple has used for iPhones and iPods for many years before introducing UBC-C with iPhone 15).
